# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type bit. UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have two data sets in `UNION ALL` however when I add date to one of the tables the `UNION ALL` returns an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type bit

Independently they work fine.

I tried to cast/convert the null value also tried to cast as int string datetime and none of it works.

```
period.CalendarDate,
[FOR_StartDate] = (CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,dateadd(month, 3, datefromparts(left(D.StartFinPeriod, 4)-1, right(D.StartFinPeriod, 2), 1))),0)),120)),
[FOR_EndDate] = (DATEADD(MONTH,12,CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,dateadd(month, 3, datefromparts(left(D.StartFinPeriod, 4)-1, right(D.StartFinPeriod, 2), 1))),0)),120))),

UNION ALL

period.CalendarDate,
[ForecastPeriod] = '',
[ForecastMonth] = '',
```

Should return data without errors everything else in `UNION` works and it breaks as soon as I add the date calculation.

[image: Desired result]

Comment: You need to show us some sample data, and provide a complete query which reproduces the issue using said sample data. [mre]

Comment: And nothing you have shown appears to be attempting to convert to a `bit`?